# I am getting this error. TypeError: must be str, not float

Tags: python

```
from ast import literal_eval
```

features = ['cast', 'crew', 'keywords', 'genres']
for feature in features:
    df1[feature] = df1[feature].apply(literal_eval)

def get_director(x):
    for i in x:
        if i['job'] == 'Director':
            return i['name']
    return np.nan
def get_list(x):
    if isinstance(x, list):
        names = [i['name'] for i in x]
        #Check if more than 3 elements exist. If yes, return only first three. If no, return entire list.
        if len(names) > 3:
            names = names[:3]
        return names

```
#Return empty list in case of missing/malformed data
return []
```

df1['director'] = df1['crew'].apply(get_director)

features = ['cast', 'keywords', 'genres']
for feature in features:
    df1[feature] = df1[feature].apply(get_list)

def clean_data(x):
    if isinstance(x, list):
        return [str.lower(i.replace(" ", "")) for i in x]
    else:
        #Check if director exists. If not, return empty string
        if isinstance(x, str):
            return str.lower(x.replace(" ", ""))
        else:
            return ''

def create_soup(x):
    return ' '.join(x['keywords']) + ' ' + ' '.join(x['cast']) + ' ' + x['director'] + ' ' + ' '.join(x['genres'])
df1['soup'] = df1.apply(create_soup, axis=1)

when I am trying to execute my create _soup it is giving an error of **"TypeError: must be str, not float"**  Please assist.

Comment: Please format it so we are able to read it easily.

Comment: Is the float coming from  `return np.nan` ? Try changing that return value to type str (e.g. '')

Comment: Please while you are editing your post so it displays correctly also add the full traceback. It contains more useful information than just that error line. Help us help you.